# Excel drop down list reflect changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if it is possilbe with a drop down list, that if I have a selected item fom a range of cells that if the cell thats been referenced is change for it to update/reflect the change in the drop down list?

Example

```
a1 = Apples
a2 = Oranges 
a3 = Bananas

Dropdown list selection is Oranges

I now want to change cell a2 = Strawberry
```

The dropdown will remain saying Oranges and not strawberry. is there any vba code to make it update the dropdown list?

Comment: The dropdown list should update once you click on the drown arrow again after your change

Comment: What kind of drop-down list is it?

Comment: Hello Windmill.  Assuming this is a Data Validation list, please look into the Worksheet_Change event.  This link provides a lot of good information for beginners: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx

Comment: Hi I'm aware of the event change for any controls on my worksheet, even with that link I am still not sure how I would proceed for event changes in a Data Validation List, I only have beginner experiance with VB so any more pointers would be helpful?